# Rails add nested attribute in edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, nested-attributes

I have 2 models with many to many association as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :remark_users, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :designated_remarks, :through => :remark_users, :source => :remark
end

class Remark < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :remark_users, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :remark_users

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :remark_users
end
```

And the relationship:

```
class RemarkUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :remark
    belongs_to :user
end
```

In the remarks_controller, I have this:

```
def add_user
    @remark = Remark.find(params[:id])

    3.times { @remark.remark_users.build }
end
```

To a remark is possible to associate many users. The association would have to take place after the remark is being created, since it has to pass a validation first.

So I want to add users to a remark after it is validated. Anyway, my form, which is below, doesn't show any fields for choosing users, only the remark data is shown.

```
<p>
    <strong>Description:</strong>
    <%= @remark.description %>
</p>

<h4>Add Users</h4>

<% form_for @remark do |f| %>

    <% f.fields_for :@designated_user do |u| %>
    <p>User:<br />
    <%= u.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :user_name, {:include_blank => true}, {:class=>'form-control'}) %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: can you post the whole form? I would recommend you to use the gem [NestedForm](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), its pretty straightforward to use.

Comment: That is the whole form. In the first part I only show the Remark data. I only need to save the relationship in the remar_users table.